# Retrieve User Information using EWS Managed API 2.0

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have an ASP .NET MVC web application that authenticates users against an Office 365/Exchange Online repository. Once my application has authenticated the user, I want to retrieve some basic information about the user such as his/her first name, last name, office phone number, etc. I can't seem to find this in the object model of the EWS Managed API 2.0. Does anyone know which class, or classes, provided this data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the DLL? You can grab that from NuGet by searching "exchange managed" and looking for the 2.0 version. [Where can I get the latest Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10401834/19626) also discusses grabbing it from Microsoft's Downloads section.

From there, you'll be pulling in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data in your using statement.

If it helps, I've been using [Getting started with the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633626.aspx) to try to get up and running, too.

Answer (score -1):

you can try EWS Autodiscover. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900154(v=exchg.150).aspx